# How can following function implemented in order to caluclate accuracy?

Tags: python

I have a dataset, where I need to evaluate my model using the following formula-

```
For each symbol calculate:
X = Median of  (predicted_price-close_price)/close_price

Final_accuracy = Average of X
```

The Symbol Feature in Dataset consists of 785 unique categorical values and I have converted it into numeric ones using LabelEncoder. I have built a model and have done prediction on the test set and I need to evaluate my model's performance. How can I write a function to evaluate my models performance?
Dataset -

```
   symbol   date_txn  close_price  predicted_price  txn_year  txn_month  \
0       0 2014-12-02        47.55            47.93      2014         12   
1       0 2014-12-03        47.93            49.33      2014         12   
2       0 2014-12-04        49.33            50.68      2014         12   
3       0 2014-12-05        50.68            50.50      2014         12   
4       0 2014-12-08        50.50            48.00      2014         12   

   txn_week  txn_day  txn_dayofweek  
0        49        2              1  
1        49        3              2  
2        49        4              3  
3        49        5              4  
4        50        8              0
```

Symbol Feature-

```
0            0
1            0
2            0
3            0
4            0

1048570    784
1048571    784
1048572    784
1048573    784
1048574    784
Name: symbol, Length: 1048575, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample df:**

```
    symbol  date_txn    close_price predicted_price  txn_year    txn_month
0   1       2014-12-02  47.55       47.93            2014        12
1   0       2014-12-03  47.93       49.33            2014        12
2   1       2014-12-04  49.33       50.68            2014        12
3   2       2014-12-05  50.68       50.50            2014        12
4   2       2014-12-08  50.50       48.00            2014        12
```

You can apply your formula like this:

```
def formula(x):
    return np.median((x.predicted_price - x.close_price)/x.close_price)

x = df.groupby(['symbol']).apply(formula)
print(np.mean(x))
```

---

**x:**

```
symbol
0    0.029209
1    0.017679
2   -0.026528
dtype: float64
```

---

**Output:**

```
0.006786696895188317
```